# power function exponent JOptionPane java

Tags: java, joptionpane, dialog, exponent

*I am stuck on an assignment I am very beginning in java and the assignment is having to use the JOptionPane to calculate an exponent. I am totally lost and dont even know where to start. Here is part of the assignment instructions*

*****The Power function calculates the power of a base "a" raised to an exponent "n". Write a class which that you will call Power class with a method power() that prints the corresponding power value. Remember to use "float" for a and "long" for n and the returned value to be a "float" because the number is a real number.**

Simplified, Given two numbers `n` and `a` where `a` can have decimals and `n` can be negative. Create a function to calculate the power.

Design and write a Dialog box for Input/Ouput that allows the users to input a base "a" and an exponent "n" and outputs the result of the power of a raised to the exponent of n.

Example:

power(5.0,2)=(5.0)2= 25.0

power(5.0,-2)=(5.0)-2 = (1/25)=0.04.

Remember the values of n can be postive or negative. Your code should be able to deal with both cases. Remember to limit the value of n to the value 40 maximum.
The Assigment will require you to create 2 files:

1- Power.java which contain the details of creating the Power class and the method power which should calculate the power of any number a raised to the exponent n. (Use the Discussion 'Hints on Assign6" for help with writing the code for Power.java as an example). Remember that you:

a- We need two instance variables: float a and int n.

b- We need a constrcutor that has two parameters in order: one a float and one an int.

c- "power()" method that you need to write: one loop for n>0 and another loop for n<0. Note that power() does not have any paramters but returns a float as follows:

float power(){ }***

2- PowerJDialog.java which is modeled after the Dialog boxes developed in the book in chapter2 in pages 99-100 in the code-listing 2-32 (NamesDialog.java) for input and output.

Remember that you will prompt the user to enter:

a base "a"
an exponent "n.
And out of these 2 values you will be able to create the object "pow" of the "Power" class using the constructor. Then you will use the dialog box to print to the user the result of the power of a raised to the exponent of n.

Remember the values of n can be positive or negative. Your code of Power.java should be able to deal with both cases. Remember to limit the value of n to the value 40 maximum.

You have to have 2 files, the first one that sets the rules and the professor has given a hint:

The example below covers the case of n>0. You need to cover both >0 and <0.

```
class Power{

float power (){

float pow=1;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
pow=pow*x;

return pow;
}

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I dont know how to write the code to calculate exponents, I've seen some code written to calculate but because it uses the dialogbox and the requires 2 files I am lost. This is supposed to be a java I class for beginners and if it went by the book chapter assignment it would be fine but the teacher is giving us advanced assignments that unless you already know java you cant figure it out.

Comment: Are you reading the numbers from a file? Also are you not allowed to use the Math.pow(x,y); function?

Comment: the book does show that is how exponent is calculated but i'm literally copying and pasting everything he said to do, thats all the information he gives us, he didnt say NOT to he doesnt say anything otherwise so i can only assume its ok to use. You have the exact same info that i have

Comment: Does my solution I posted below work?

Comment: The solutions yes does work for the first file i must submit i believe because i did have something similar but used 'x' instead of 'a' would you be able to communicate outside of this post I have a facebook page listed on my bio where i can message more easily do you know anything about dialog boxes in the code it shows up like this: JOptionPane.showInputDialog("null, what is the base number?") if i had any clue what to do I wouldnt ask so many questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you professor means that there is the possibility that it will be given a negative exponent, you should make an If statement then two different cases. Case two for negatives will do the same except that in the end it will divide one by the result because x^-1 = 1/x. Also, you need to take input from your method where `a` is a float and `n` a long

```
public float power(float a, long n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                a = a * n;
            }

            return a;
        } else if (n < 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                a = a * n;
            }
            a = 1 / a;
            return a;
        }else{
            return 0f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: surprisingly I do understand your code, we are only on chapter six and just learned else-if statements last chapter, the only people doing well have already done java or some type of code before, thank you for the help this gets me at least some area to start I just have to add the dialog boxes to this somewhere